# AWS ruby sdk v2 - dynamodb query

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a hash (string) and range (number) table in DynamoDB. I'm trying to run a query using the ruby SDK v2.0.30 but keep getting the following error:

`` aws-sdk-core-2.0.30/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException) ``

Here is my code:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
require 'aws-sdk'

dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1', credentials: creds)
resp = dynamodb.query(
      table_name: "TEST_TABLE",
      key_conditions: {
        'ID' => {
          comparison_operator: 'EQ',
          attribute_value_list: [{ 's' => 'test123' }]
        }
      })
```

I'm new to ruby and have tried looking online and on AWS docs but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#query-instance_method   The attrivute_value_list, expects a "value". So that would be 'test123' if that's the value. You also don't mention which field is the HK and which one is the RK, so guessing ID is the Rk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is in how you formatted the value of the hash key in your query expression. The v2 AWS SDK for Ruby (`aws-sdk` gem) accepts all attribute values as vanilla Ruby values.

A ***value*** can be:

- String
- Numeric (Integer, Float, BigDecimal, etc)
- Boolean
- IO (blob type)
- Set (of Numeric/String)
- Array (of *values*)
- Hash (String => *value*)

You do not need to provide the type hint as was required with the v1 AWS SDK for Ruby.

```
ddb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new
ddb.query({
  table_name: 'TEST_TABLE',
  key_conditions: {
    'ID' => {
      comparison_operattor: 'EQ',
      attribute_value_list: ['test-123']      
    }
  }
})
```

Also, not directly related to you question, but you may find the following blog series helpful when working with DynamoDB from the `aws-sdk` gem:

- [part 1 - projection expressions](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxVB6GNOC13QSM/Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-API-in-Ruby-Part-1-Projection-Expressions)
- [part 2 - condition expressions](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1MFYEN4VA16U6/Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-API-in-Ruby-Part-2-Condition-Expressions)
- [part 3 - update expressions](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1T1UIV3BDRCOC/Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-API-in-Ruby-Part-3-Update-Expressions)

Comment: Feel a sense of relief using the above tip to see my query work! Its was like searching for the needle in the haystack... Thx a ton!

Comment: comparison_operattor [ typo ]